# Tabs become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am trying to replicate the "tabs" section as explained in this tutorial: [Google material Design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html?optionsRadios=option2). Everthing works fine except when I insert a date which uses a datepicker widget from this url: [Datepicker](http://curioussolutions.github.io/DateTimePicker/). As soon as I select the date all the tabs in Megamenu become unresponsive

HTML code for the tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#remindertab" data-toggle="tab">Reminder</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#">
                 Reports <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#dropdown1" data-toggle="tab">Insurance History Between Dates</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#dropdown2" data-toggle="tab">Insurance history of Account</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#dropdown3" data-toggle="tab">Insurance Amount between dates</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Bulletin Board</a></li>

        <p class="user" data-toggle="tab">Welcome Wasim(1117004017)</p>
</ul>
```

Script for datepicker:

```
$("#dtBox").DateTimePicker();
```

This renders Megamenu like this:

[image]

One more strange thing I came across is that as soon as tabs become unresponsive and I click on "Reports" tab I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the fault of the DatePicker plugin. This line of code

```
$(document).unbind('click')
```

stopped bootstrap's propagation of the menu.